# How to combine bits into larger integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Wondering what the ideal way is of converting a group of smaller bits into larger bits. For example, these specific cases:

- 3 8-bit numbers to 1 24-bit number.
- 2 16-bit numbers into 1 32-bit number.

Wondering what the generic technique is so I can apply it to any number. If it only works for multiples of 8 then that's fine, but ideally it would be able to handle these cases as well.

- 3 7-bit numbers to 1 21-bit number.
- 9 3-bit numbers to 1 27-bit number.

I was thinking you just add them but it sounds like there is a technique for shifting them which I'm not sure exactly how it works generically.

Comment: It depends a lot on what "converting" means in this case. (It could be almost anything.)

Comment: Basically I mean the reverse of splitting a 24 bit number into 3 8-bit numbers, however that might be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "convert" you mean to "concatenate" the bits.

Here's how you would do that with shift:

```js
var int1 = 23; // "8 bit" number, stored in integer variable
var int2 = 67; // another one
var int3 = 189; // a third
var concatInt = ( int1 << 16 ) + ( int2 << 8 ) + int3;
```

Here, the value of "concatInt" is the bitwise concatenation of the 3 numbers [int1][int2][int3]

Of course, you can do this with any numbers and any bits, as long as you fit within a 32 bit integer.

Here is some more reading on that:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Not sure if this works with all the cases described in the post, let me know which it works for. Thank you.

Comment: I know about the bitwise operators, just not how to use them for things like this.

Comment: You just offset by the number of bits you're interested in. For your 3 7-bit situation, just offset by 14 and 7 respectively, instead of 16 and 8 in my example.

Comment: @user10869858 Did this work for you? Or would you like more specific examples in the code sample?